# Mapping a textual method name to a function

Tags: c++, c++11

My program (a daemon hosting a Minecraft server) exposes a D-Bus interface to allow interaction with the server from other processes. To that end, and to avoid a chain of repetitive conditionals in the invocation handler, I'm using a map of `Glib::ustring` keys (the method invoked) to `std::bind`-created function objects (code abbreviated slightly; see end of question for link to full source):

```
std::unordered_map<Glib::ustring, std::function<void(Minecraftd1*, const Glib::RefPtr<Gio::DBus::MethodInvocation>&)>> handlerMap;
std::once_flag handlerMapInitFlag;

Minecraftd::Minecraftd1() {
    // Only initialise the method name/handler method map once. Placeholders are used for the "this" and invocation arguments.
    std::call_once(handlerMapInitFlag, []{
        using namespace std::placeholders;
        handlerMap.emplace("SaveAll", std::bind(&Minecraftd1::handleSimpleCommand, _1, _2, "save-all"));
        // Omitted: two similar mappings
        handlerMap.emplace("Stop", std::bind(&Minecraftd1::handleSimpleCommand, _1, _2, "stop"));
    });
}

// Called by the Glib main loop when a D-Bus method call is received
void Minecraftd1::onMethodCall(const Glib::ustring &methodName, const Glib::RefPtr<Gio::DBus::MethodInvocation> &invocation) {
    auto handler = handlerMap.find(methodName);
    if(handler != handlerMap.end()) {
        handler->second(this, invocation);
    } else {
        invocation->return_error(Gio::DBus::Error{Gio::DBus::Error::UNKNOWN_METHOD, "Method does not exist."});
    }
}

void Minecraftd1::handleSimpleCommand(const Glib::RefPtr<Gio::DBus::MethodInvocation> &invocation, std::string command) const {
    // Write value of command to standard input (rebound to a pipe)
    invocation->return_value(Glib::VariantContainerBase{});
}
```

I realise that, for the current set of methods, I could just as well use a map of `methodName` to the command string to write to the file descriptor, but this way of doing it allows me to create more complex handlers for commands that require more than just a simple pass-through without having to change the execution flow of `onMethodCall`. Of course, if a handler method requires access to e.g. the parameters of the D-Bus invocation, I would need to modify the signature of all the handlers to accept it as an argument, with a corresponding additional placeholder in the `std::bind` call.

Is this a good way of going about runtime dispatch based on a string identifier, or am I barking up the wrong tree here? Is there any way that it could be improved further?

---

*The full source code may be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/slyfoxza/minecraftd/blob/b53957a662f009723c3ae1ca80542aff5df9210f/src/minecraftd-dbus.cpp).*

Comment: There is not enough context in the question to review. I like the idea but can't comment on the quality of the code because I can tell what the types are.

Comment: @LokiAstari I'm not sure I understand what you feel is missing. If you can expand on that I am happy to add more detail to the question.

Answer (score 3):

`std::call_once` is an interesting tool, but there are alternatives built into the language: namely, you can use the [Immediately-Invoked Function Expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) (IIFE) borrowed straight from JavaScript and made usable thanks to C++11 lambda functions.

Here is how you can use it to initialize `handlerMap`:

```
std::unordered_map<
    Glib::ustring,
    std::function<void(Minecraftd1*, const Glib::RefPtr<Gio::DBus::MethodInvocation>&)>
> handlerMap = []{
    using namespace std::placeholders;
    std::unordered_map<
        Glib::ustring,
        std::function<void(Minecraftd1*, const Glib::RefPtr<Gio::DBus::MethodInvocation>&)>
    > initMap;
    initMap.emplace("SaveAll", std::bind(&Minecraftd1::handleSimpleCommand, _1, _2, "save-all"));
    initMap.emplace("Stop", std::bind(&Minecraftd1::handleSimpleCommand, _1, _2, "stop"));
    return initMap;
}();
```

Agreed, it looks a bit messy with the big `std::unordered_map` type, but you could probably create a type alias to get rid of the syntactic mess. Even if you dont typedef the whole thing, I guess that exposing the type of `std::function<void(Minecraftd1*, const Glib::RefPtr<Gio::DBus::MethodInvocation>&)>` could be an interesting idea.

Alterntively, there is even better than IIFE: in your can, you can use initializer lists to achieve what you're trying to do:

```
std::unordered_map<
    Glib::ustring,
    std::function<void(Minecraftd1*, const Glib::RefPtr<Gio::DBus::MethodInvocation>&)>
> handlerMap = {
    { "SaveAll", std::bind(&Minecraftd1::handleSimpleCommand, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, "save-all") },
    { "Stop",    std::bind(&Minecraftd1::handleSimpleCommand, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, "stop") }
};
```

But it means that you have to explicitly write `std::placeholders::` everywhere if you don't want `using std::placeholders;` to leak into the outer namespace. In other words, you have to choose which solutions seems to best convey your idea while not bearing too much syntactic noise.